# Accessing apache HTTP server over the internet

Tags: apache

I have an apache HTTP server set up in my computer. Can I access it from anywhere over the internet? I don't have a registered domain for my server.

Answer (score 2):

You can access it if you tell your router to forward your HTTP port. If your router does not know to forward it, you will only be able to access it on your local network. You do have to buy a domain, unless you just access the network-wide IP, you can find this on [whatsmypi](http://www.whatsmyip.org/). So, to summarize, you need to do 2 things: (1) tell your router to forward the HTTP port, and (2) access it via the internet by means of your IP (unless you buy a domain name).

**UPDATE**

Of course this is one of those "easier said than done" and "one size does not fit all" things. There will probably be a set of difficulties that come along with your attempts to access your HTTP server. I would suggest googling some tutorials.